# Example of cache friendly code

Tags: c++, caching

```
template<size_t size>
class Objects{
  std::array<int,size> a;
  std::array<int,size> b;
  std::array<int,size> c;

  void update(){
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i){
      c[i] = a[i] + b[i];
    }
  }
};
```

I am gathering information of how to write cache friendly code since a week and I read though several articles but I still haven't understood the basics.

Code like I have written above is used in most of the examples, but for me this is not cache friendly at all.

For me the memory layout should look like this

```
aaaabbbbcccc
```

and in the first loop it will access

```
[a]aaa[b]bbb[c]ccc
```

If I understood it correctly, the cpu prefetches elements that are near in memory. I am not sure how intelligent this method is but I assume it's primitive and it just fetches the nth nearest elements.

The problem is that `[a]aaa[b]bbb[c]ccc` will not access the elements in order at all. So it might fetch the next '3' elements `a[aaa]bbbbcccc` which is nice for the next a because it will be a cache hit but not for the b.

Is the example above cache friendly code?

Comment: Could you define `cache friendly` a bit more please?

Comment: The cache holds several "areas" of RAM simultaneously. You should study the concept of "cache lines".

Comment: @molbdnilo Thanks that is probably the missing piece of information that I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you use an array of structures:

```
struct Cache_Item
{
  int a;
  int b;
  int c;
};

Cache_Item cache_line[size];

for (unsigned int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
{
  cache_line[i].c = cache_line[i].a + cache_line[i].b;
}
```

The structure arrangement allows for all the variables in use to be next to each other in the cache line or very close.

In your array method, element b[0] ideally is at location a[size], so they are `size` items apart.  This could mean that they are on different cache lines.  The result location, c[0], is at a[size + size], which means it could be 2 cache lines away.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not particularly unfriendly. It requires three active cache lines at a time instead of one, but that isn't too much to ask. Your code would be a lot more cache-unfriendly if instead of

```
std::array<int,size> a;
```

you had

```
std::array<struct { int x; char description[5000]; }, size> a;
```

because then the CPU would have to pick out the lone `x` among the thousands of bytes of `description` (which your loop never uses).

Your example would also be more cache-unfriendly if you had not just `a`, `b`, and `c`, but also `d`-`z` and `aa`-`az` and maybe a few more. (How far you have to go depends on the sophistication of your cache - how many way-associative it is, etc.)

Have you profiled yours vs Thomas Matthews' code?

Answer (score 0):

You should trust the compiler optimization work (and of course enable optimizations); it probably deals quite well with the [CPU cache](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_cache) (perhaps by issuing appropriate [prefetch instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3122915/841108)).

Sometimes you can hint the compiler thru builtins or pragmas. For example with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) on x86-64 you might -with care- use the [__builtin_prefetch](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html). Usually it is not worth the effort (and if you misuse it performance will suffer). See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8460606/841108) to a related question.

Comment: The compiler is not free to rearrange struct layouts - it's bound by the platform's ABI. While "trust the compiler" is a good meta-answer, this isn't a meta-question.

Comment: The compiler could rearrange layout of struct if it can prove that the struct data does not escape its compilation unit. GCC used to have such an optimization pass.